# Python P2P Networking (NAT Punchtrough)

Tags: python, sockets, networking

So for sake of understanding, we're going to assume both machines are on ipv4 and behind NAT networks. I'd like to be able to open a socket on both machines and have the machines connect through those sockets (or a similar system). I know nat punchthrough is required for this, but I'm not sure how nat punchtrough applies (can a socket that was once connecting now be accepting?) Anyone who has worked with nat punchthrough in python I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you using UDP or TCP?

Comment: I could use either, I haven't picked one in particular. I'm also not ultra familiar with the difference.

Comment: TCP packets are reliable and will be reassembled in order at the other end. UDP is unreliable (packets can be silently lost, or received out of order) but is often used when dropping packets is preferable to resending them due to time constraints (eg games, audio/video chat)

Comment: these projects may interest you: [nattraverso](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nattraverso) and [PyPunchP2P](https://github.com/laike9m/PyPunchP2P)

Answer (score 4):

This is called **"NAT traversal problem"**.
**There are three solutions**:

1. Statically configure NAT to forward incoming connection requests at given port to your server. It is called also **port forwarding**
   [image]
2. **Internet Gateway Device (IGD) Protocol**.  Allows NATed host to:
   -learn public IP address of the NAT router 
   -add/remove port mappings (with lease times)
   i.e., automate static NAT port map configuration
   [image]
3. **Relaying** (used in Skype)
   -NATed client establishes connection to relay/server
   -external client connects to relay
   -relay bridges packets between to connections
   [image]

Please refer the book **Computer Networking A Top-Down Approach 6th edition-James F. Kurose, Keith W. Ross** chapter 4>>Network Address Translation (NAT) for more information

Answer (score 2):

Hole punching is described well in [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking))

> Hole punching is a computer networking technique for establishing communications between two parties in separate organizations who are both behind restrictive firewalls. Used for applications such as online gaming, P2P and VoIP, both clients establish a connection with an unrestricted third-party server that uncovers external and internal address information for them. Since each client initiated the request to the server, the server knows their IP addresses and port numbers assigned for that session, which it shares one to the other. Having valid port numbers causes the firewalls to accept the incoming packets from each side. ICMP hole punching, UDP hole punching and TCP hole punching respectively use Internet Control Message, User Datagram and Transmission Control Protocols. Using TCP nefarious hole punching, it is possible to send compressed SYN packets through into a common ACK path.

There are links there for the various techniques for TCP, UDP and ICMP hold punching.

Generally, to punch a hole from A to B (both behind NAT) requires a 3rd party server C that they can both initially connect to. The server sends the connection information of A to B and vice versa. A & B then use this information to try to connect directly to each other, but the process is not 100% reliable.

If you do not have the 3rd party server, then I don't think it will work.

**EDIT**

You might also like to take a look into UPnP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#NAT_traversal. I'm not sure how well supported it is by routers, but it sounds appropriate for your application.

Comment: I do have a third party server (theoretically). It's an extracurricular project I'm leading through our school's ACM so we have access to server space on the ACM's server. I was planning on hole punching through that. Still a little lost on implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set up port forwarding -- essentially tell your router to forward calls it receives on a specific port to a service that sits behind it.

That's usually done through your router's admin interface.

Comment: I particularly am looking into nat punchthrough in an effort to avoid that. I'm trying to create software that's relatively easy to use, and so configuring the router doesn't sound reasonable.

Comment: As far as I know, you absolutely need to use port forwarding at least in one direction. Once you have a connection established, then it's possible to simply send packets over that connection. If you don't want the user to intervene, I believe you can use UPnP, which allows you to set up port forwarding straight from your application.  I have never tried that though, so I'm not sure how easy it would be.